# How to check if a property from an object in a List<T> exists in another List<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, list

Friendly Notice:
I am aware of the nested foreach method, but I'm trying to avoid it if there is a more efficient way.

Setup of Class 1:

```
public class Product{

      public int ID {get; set;}
      //Other irrelevant properties
}
```

Setup of Class 2:

```
public class JoinedDiscounts{

      public int ID {get; set;}
      public List<Product> Products = new List<Product>();
      //Other irrelevant properties

}
```

Suppose I now have a list of products (I've filtered specific products out into this list):

```
List<Product> products;
```

I also have this list.

```
List<JoinedDiscount> joinedDiscounts;
```

My goal is to check if any of the Joined Discounts from the `joinedDiscounts` list have a list of Products wherein any Product from the `products` list exists.

I think I've spent too much time thinking about it and now I'm having difficulty figuring out something that's probably very simple.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Maybe use [reflection](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_reflection.htm)?

Comment: Friendly Notice: The accepted answer (and all others in this thread) is everything else (more readable, shorter) but not more efficient. Basically it's a 3 nested `foreach` methods with extra compiler generated class, extra class instance created, local variables turned into a class fields and some delegates created and invoked.  Welcome to the LINQ world. Next time make sure using words like "fancy", "cool", "modern" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you an enumeration of the `JoinedDiscount`s in `joinedDiscounts` that contain a `Product` in `products`.

```
joinedDiscounts.Where(disc => disc.Products.Any(prod => products.Contains(prod)))
```

I *think* that covers what you're looking for.

Comment: How do I loop through the results? Right now this would be returning bool. I need a list of the matches found, please :)

Comment: If you simply want a `bool` that states that *at least* one of the `joinedDiscounts` matches the case, then change the `Where` to an `Any`.

Comment: The query returns an `IEnumerable` that you can iterate over. If you have a hard requirement of a `List` for some reason, simply tack on `.ToList()`

Comment: I'd highly suggest learning Linq for stuff like this. Very handy for working with sets/collections.  :)

Comment: Yeah I've been using a lot of `Where x=>x.prop {operator} {value}` queries, but I need to get more into the complex side of it.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start from the top down...

> if any of the Joined Discounts

Ok, so the outer structure is:

```
joinedDiscounts.Any()
```

But we need a boolean clause in there...

> have a list of Products wherein any

Ok, we want to examine the `.Products` property and know if anything in that list matches a condition:

```
joinedDiscounts.Any(jd => jd.Products.Any())
```

Now we need a boolean clause in *there*...

> any Product from the products list exists

So, if the `products` contains any given product of this collection?

```
joinedDiscounts.Any(jd => jd.Products.Any(p => products.Contains(p)))
```

That ought to do it, at least semantically.

*However*, if the comparator for `Product` isn't defined on that class then the code might just do a reference comparison, which might not be what you want.  (Two instances may have the same values and may *conceptually* represent the same product, but they wouldn't *be* the same instance of the `Product` class.)  If you need to drill further into the `ID` to manually compare, you'd have to do something like this:

```
joinedDiscounts.Any(jd => jd.Products.Any(prod => products.Select(p => p.ID).Contains(prod.ID)))
```

As the code grows, I'd recommend encapsulating comparison logic into your models appropriately.  Implementing `.Equals()` and `.GetHashCode()` should do the trick in this case.  That way consuming code stays simple and the logic is encapsulated on the objects where it belongs.  That would allow you to perform semantically intuitive comparisons of your objects instead of drilling in to `ID` values manually.

Comment: I understand thanks to your simple way of explaining it. I appreciate this. :)

Comment: Apparently someone disagrees by way of a down-vote :-/  But I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
joinedDiscounts.Where(joinedDiscountse => joinedDiscountse.Products.Any()).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using linq you can do this

```
List<JoinedDiscount> joinedDiscounts; //the joined products
List<Product> products; //desired products


joinedDiscounts.Where(d => d.Products.Any(
                     p => products.Select(prod => prod.ID).Contains(p.ID)
                     ).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you tell me why you compare the IDs instead of the objects themselves?

Comment: Just out of habit,  I don't know whether you would be going through linq to entityframework or if it was on linq objects,  but Id rather compare on a known unique field, because then the operation will be the same vs if you were to compare the entity, you would be doing something entirely different in sql than what you would be doing in objects, SQL would most likely end up comparing the entire row instead of just the id